# How to approach implementation of mutiple-sites inside a django application?

Tags: django, multiple-databases

**Requirement:** enable **one instance** of your Django application to serve multiple clients. By client we can mean different domains or different accounts that are not supposed to access each other's data.

The estimated number of clients, is around hundreds.

I'm sure that there are many, but I'm looking for the one what would minimize the effort in the long run. Two of them could be:

1. One would be to use the [sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) in Django and one database and add a `site_id` for most models (sounds scary)
2. Usa one database for authentication and sites module and use the [multi-database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) feature for keeping client specific models data in a separate database. This scares me too because I should implement dynamic database creation for new clients and worse, I do not know how to handle database migration when I upgrade the application.

What is your recommended approach for this?

Comment: I think option number 2 won't be considerable anymore if you need to share data across your sites - so youre sure this won't be a requirement?

Comment: I do not want to share data across sites, in fact the only thing that has to be centralized is the sites configuration and account management. The super-admin should be able to administer sites and create admin accounts, accounts that do have access to only one specific site.

Comment: so why make one project out of these then? you could just make your own authorization backend that enables you to login on both sites...

Comment: The main reason for doing that is because you want to be able to allow people to create/register new sites. Also, I do no want to require users to have to specify the site on the login form.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have multiple instances of the same application with a different SITE_ID for each site, then that would be the preferred option. That way you could either using a different database for each site, or reliably use the Django sites framework.

It is possible if you want a single process or a handful of processes to serve hundreds of sites, however it's bending the current design of Django. Using `Site.objects.get_current()` relies on SITE_ID, so you'll have to use something else to figure out the current site.

One package which offers the functionality you need is [django-threaded-multihost](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-threaded-multihost), you can use `get_current_host` on a per request basis to get a different site.

The only downside would be that any Django apps which use `Site.objects.get_current()` will need modification with such a setup, making it difficult to use certain pluggable applications awkward to use - you'll either have to monkey patch them or stick with apps you've created yourself for threaded-multihost usage in mind.

So, it's possible, but it just isn't that great with Django at the moment.